# How do I prevent onTapDown from being triggered on a parent widgets GestureDetector?

Tags: flutter, gesture-recognition

I have a Stack in which several widget can be dragged around. In addition, the container that the Stack is in has a GestureDetector to trigger on onTapDown and onTapUp. I want those onTap events only to be triggered when the user taps outside of the widget in the Stack. I've tried the following code:

```
class Gestures extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _GesturesState();
}

class _GesturesState extends State<Gestures> {
  Color background;
  Offset pos;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pos = Offset(10.0, 10.0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => GestureDetector(
    onTapDown: (_) => setState(() => background = Colors.green),
    onTapUp: (_) => setState(() => background = Colors.grey),
    onTapCancel: () => setState(() => background = Colors.grey),
        child: Container(
          color: background,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                top: pos.dy,
                left: pos.dx,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                  onPanUpdate: _onPanUpdate,
//                  onTapDown: (_) {},  Doesn't affect the problem
                  child: Container(
                    width: 30.0,
                    height: 30.0,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );

  void _onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    setState(() {
      pos = renderBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    });
  }
}
```

However, when starting to drag the widget, the onTap of the outermost container is triggered as well, making the background momentarily go green in this case. Settings `HitTestBehavior.opaque` doesn't seem to work like I'd expect. Neither does adding a handler for onTapDown to the widget in the Stack.

So, how do I prevent onTapDown from being triggered on the outermost GestureDetector when the user interacts with the widget inside of the Stack?

*Update:*

An even simpler example of the problem I'm encountering:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTapDown: (_) {
    print("Green");
  },
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.green,
    width: 300.0,
    height: 300.0,
    child: Center(
      child: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTapDown: (_) {
          print("Red");
        },
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 50.0,
          height: 50.0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

When I tap and hold the red container, both "Red" and "Green" are printed even though the inner GestureDetector has `HitTestBehavior.opaque`.

Comment: I don't know if it can help, but cuold you try chanhe outer `GestureDetector` to `Listener`?

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Just replacing the outer detector with a Listener and using onPointerDown etc. like I used onTapDown does fix the problem. (This is a reduced example, in the real code the outer GestureDetector is further up the stack in a different Widget. So I'd prefer no to change that GestureDetector if possible)

Comment: I encountered the same issue, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @RasitAyaz I've created https://pub.dev/packages/transparent_pointer for this.

Comment: I tried that package but it doesn't seem to work in my situation. Parent's `onTap` function is not being triggered but its `onTapDown` function is being triggered. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I could get the behavior that I wanted (making a widget appear transparent to it parent, while still responding to pointer events) by creating a render object with hit test behavior like this:

```dart
  @override
  bool hitTest(BoxHitTestResult result, {@required Offset position}) {
    // forward hits to our child:
    final hit = super.hitTest(result, position: position);
    // but report to our parent that we are not hit when `transparent` is true:
    return false;
  }
```

I've published a package with a widget having this behavior here: https://pub.dev/packages/transparent_pointer.

Answer (score 4):

In this answer, I'll solve the simpler example you have given. You are creating the following Widget hierarchy:

```
 - GestureDetector       // green
   - Container
     - Center
       - GestureDetector // red
          - Container
```

Therefore the **red** [GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) is a child Widget of the **green** GestureDetector. The **green** GestureDetector has the default [HitTestBehavior](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/HitTestBehavior-class.html): `HitTestBehavior.deferToChild`. That is why `onTapDown` is fired for both containers.

> Targets that defer to their children receive events within their
>   bounds only if one of their children is hit by the hit test.

Instead, you can use a Stack to build your UI:

```
 - Stack
   - GestureDetector // green
     - Container
   - GestureDetector // red
     - Container
```

This structure would result in the follwing sourcecode. It looks the same, but the behavior is the one you desired:

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (_) {
        print("Green");
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        width: 300.0,
        height: 300.0,
      ),
    ),
    GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (_) {
        print("Red");
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: 50.0,
        height: 50.0,
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

Comment: This helped me fix a very similar problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use RiverPod, and have succeeded with these steps. This is a general process, so should work for all use cases (and with your state manager)

(The use case here is to prevent a ListView from scrolling, when I select text on a widget using the mouse).

1. Create a notifier

```
final textSelectionInProgress = StateProvider<bool>((ref) {
  return false;
});
```

2. When there is an action (in my case onTap) on the widget, wrap widget with a Focus, or use the focusNode of the widget, and the following code in initState

```
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusN = FocusNode();
    focusN.addListener(() {
      if (focusN.hasFocus) {
        widget.ref.read(textSelectionInProgress.notifier).state = true;
      } else {
        widget.ref.read(textSelectionInProgress.notifier).state = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

Ensure you add this in the onDispose:

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.ref.read(textSelectionInProgress.notifier).state = false;
    super.Dispose();
  }
```

3. Add listener in the build of the widget you want to stop scrolling

```
bool textSelectionOn = ref.watch(textSelectionInProgress);
```

4. Set ScrollPhysics appropriately

```
physics: textSelectionOn
            ? NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
            : <you choice>
```